# Highcharts: How to hide the text from legends

Tags: highcharts

What I'm after is showing only the colors of the series in the legends and hiding all the text while keeping the title in the series data so it would come in the tool tip.

Through using `labelFormatter` this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hpdmonv/)) is the closest I got to doing it, when I remove the text however it allows the legends to overlap.

Eventually, just showing the colors of the legends and not the legends' text itself is the result I'm after, i.e:
[image]

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I edited the question and have added an image :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set,

```
itemStyle: {
        display: 'none',
      }
```

and remove

```
layout: 'vertical',
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/L7pr4q0s/)